# Go down a column until a certain cell and then select a cell to the right

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to automate a task using VBA but am very beginner with it.

I'm trying to select column x, go down that column until it says a certain value, and then select the cell that is one to the right of the cell that contains that value. IE go down column x until it says "apple" and then select the number to the right of the cell containing "apple"

After this, I want to go to the next sheet and perform the same action. I know I need to perform some type of loop but mostly confused about how to go down a column until a certain cell and then to the right.

Comment: You can use `Range.Find` to select the first cell and then use `Offset` to navigate one cell to the right. To have this repeat over many sheets just nest all of this in a `For Each` worksheet loop.

Comment: What is the purpose of automating selecting a cell (over multiple sheets)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to increase the range. This thread should be helpful to you.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-select-the-ranges-next-to-the-activecell/80a080aa-6355-4700-9574-83197190164a

**FYI Need to include specific code you have tried to use to resolve and specific errors if there are any. You will get less responses if you have a 'lame' question (i.e. just hoping someone else to do it for you)

Comment: Please put the information from that link here. The link might get invalid in sometime and then your answer in not useful. It is recommended to provide links for further reading but not as your answer

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! My rep isn't high enough to comment or I would have